# How to store variable 2D array via Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, arrays, entity-framework-4

I have a 2D array of values that can range in size (although, I can make a large, fixed size if needed) that I want to store in a database. Can anyone tell me the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not map each dimension to a column/property, and have another for the value?

Comment: @retailcoder I'm a database rookie - so I don't really understand how I could do this. Could you elaborate? I'm using something like EF to keep persistance work to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me a 2D array sounds like `(x,y) = somevalue`. So I'm thinking of something simple, something like this (assuming `somevalue` is an `int`):

```
public interface IArrayValueEntity
{    
    int ArrayIndexX { get; set; }
    int ArrayIndexY { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The entity type implements it like this (or you can have just the implementation if you prefer):

```
public class ArrayValue : IArrayValueEntity
{
    public int ArrayIndexX { get; set; }
    public int ArrayIndexY { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can make `ArrayIndexX` and `ArrayIndexY` be entity's primary key (and have EF enforce uniqueness of combinations of these two values) in overriding the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` if you're going *code-first*.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<ArrayValue> ArrayValues { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // there are several options here...
    }
}
```

If you don't have the database from the start, EF can create it for you (and *will* by default, if I'm not mistaken), based on how you configure your entities.

And then you can have a service that gets you a value for a given `(x,y)` key, and/or another that gets you... your 2D array back.

**EDIT**

To address the 2D array being "part of" a *map* entity, you merely need to define **navigation properties** - if you want you can also define a **foreign key property**:

```
public class Map : IMapEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // primary key
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    // Navigation property on the "one" side (note "virtual ICollection")
    public virtual ICollection<ArrayValue> ArrayValues { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayValue : IArrayValueEntity
{
    public int ArrayIndexX { get; set; }
    public int ArrayIndexY { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    // FK property
    //public int MapId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property on the "many" side (note "virtual")
    public virtual Map Map { get; set; }
}
```

Using the `modelBuilder` in `OnModelCreating` or attributes decorating the entity class members, you then configure those relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Map>().HasMany(e => e.ArrayValues)
                          .WithRequired(e => e.Map);
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I'd need - how would one attach the actual object to an another? Just make it a property and then map that property accordingly?

Comment: The mapping is kinda *automagical* - it just works (column names are after your property names, tables after your classes, etc.). Not sure I understand your question though; what do you mean "attach"?

Comment: Sorry - I have a 2D class called "Map", with a 2D array of these values. I assume I just need to attach an ArrayValue to this class, and things should just work?

Comment: I think I'd need to see this "Map" class to tell for sure... but if "Map" is  also an entity with a "one map, many coordinates" relationship with the "ArrayValues" dbset then I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a POCO that is supposed to contain 'many array values'. Think... like a grid.